# Python code to determine the position on a map using Geo-Tagging

Tags: python, geotag, position, triangulation-survey

What is a proper python code, which enables to scan photographs (when captured from a series of snapshots) and match it with a geo-tagged image database.

Based on the extent of similarities existing between captured photo and geo-tagged images, it must help in finding my position on a map.

So far, I am aware of finding latitude and longitude of an image file using following python code

```
from osgeo import gdal

geotiff= gdal.Open('C:\Users\nikhil\Desktop\north_rgb.tif')

width,height=geotiff.RasterXSize,geotiff.RasterYSize

gt = geotiff.GetGeoTransform()

minx = gt[0]

miny = gt[3] + width*gt[4] + height*gt[5]

maxx = gt[0] + width*gt[1] + height*gt[2]

maxy = gt[3]

print(minx,miny,maxx,maxy)
```

I need some extension or modification of this code as my requirement stated above.